# Discrete Event Simulation for Networking in python

Tags: python

I am working on a lab experiment, where it deals with simulating a M/M/1 queue using python. I got a code from the following website,[the code being SimComponents.py that basically defines classes for Packet generation and a PacketSink to save details of generated packet](https://www.grotto-networking.com/DiscreteEventPython.html)

I wanted to know how do I access the packet details from the outside.
Here is my code:

```
from random import expovariate
import simpy
from SimComponents import PacketGenerator, PacketSink


def distArrival(): 
    return expovariate(0.5)

def distSize():
    return expovariate(0.01)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = simpy.Environment()  # Create the SimPy environment
    # Create the packet generators and sink
    ps = PacketSink(env,absolute_arrivals=True,debug=True)  
    pg = PacketGenerator(env, "TELE4642", distArrival, distSize)
    # Wire packet generators and sink together
    pg.out = ps
    env.run(until=20) # Run it
```

Comment: define `pg` as global variable, outside of all the blocks. good place would be at the top of the file and below the import statements.